# Uploading files before the table entry is created?

Tags: ajax, html, upload

I have a form that creates entries in a database.
The entries should have associated files.
I have an AJAX/HTML5 file upload on the same form.

If a user uploads a file before the database entry is created then I don't have anything to associate with the file.  I'm not sure I can trust session_id() or rand() or microtime() to be unique.  If the database entry is never created, I need a way to detect this and delete the unneeded files.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ajax success and error methods to add to and remove from the file upload accordingly.

```
$.ajax({

    url: yourUploadURL,
    success: function( data ) {
        // If this runs then you should call a function to create the table in your DB
    },
    error: function ( error ) {
        // If this runs then you call a function to remove the file you just uploaded.
    }

});
```

Comment: Perhaps I haven't phrased the question clearly.  The issue isn't on the client side, where I know they're looking at the form and I can append the newly uploaded image.  The problem is on the backend where I don't know what the client is doing and I can be certain they're still looking at the form.